# How to update Bootstrap 3 tooltip text on each hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to just simply update the tooltip each time on hover before display.  I have a warning icon that pops up if there's been an error, and on hover I'd like the most recent error to show up.  What I have doesn't work, though.

HTML Snippet

```
<div id="title">App</div>
    <button id="warningbtn" type="button" class="btn-default btn-sm" 
                  data-toggle="errortip" data-placement="right" title="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> 
    </button>
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
function start(){
  let result = addon.start();
  if (result == -1){
      recentError = "Your license is invalid.";
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$('[data-toggle="errortip"]').tooltip({
  trigger : 'hover',
  title: errorVariable
 });
```

Start is called from a simple start button on the page.  recentError is declared at the top of the .js file.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set this attribute whenever you will need a new value for the tooltip:

```
$('#warningbtn').attr('data-original-title','something else');
```

There is an issue reported here, and it seems to be a problem with setting the tooltip title dynamically 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14769

Comment: Yep, this worked!  You rock!  Thanks a ton, dude!  Amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use data-original-title attribute on show.bs.tooltip event:

```js
var errorVariable = Date.now() % 100;

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="errortip"]').tooltip({
    trigger : 'hover',
    title: errorVariable
  }).on('show.bs.tooltip', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('data-original-title', errorVariable);
  });

  $('#myBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    errorVariable = Date.now() % 100;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn-default btn-sm" id="myBtn">Click Me to create a random tooltip message</button>
<div id="title">App</div>
<button id="warningbtn" type="button" class="btn-default btn-sm"
        data-toggle="errortip" data-placement="right" title="">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: For some reason, nothing actually pops up when I use this code.

Comment: That code for the tooltip isn't working.  It's causing an error on load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#warningbtn').on('show.bs.tooltip', function() {
    $('#warningbtn').tooltip({
      title: errorVariable
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code. I have updated according to your requirement. :

```js
var recentError;
 function start() {
  var result = -1;
  if (result == -1) {
   recentError = "Your license is invalid.";
  }
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('[data-toggle="errortip"]').tooltip({

   title : recentError
  });
 });
 start();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div id="title">App</div>
 <button id="warningbtn" type="button" class="btn-default btn-sm"
  data-toggle="errortip" data-placement="right" title="">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
 </button>
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  That doesn't update the tooltip when hovering over it.  It's stuck at what was original in recentError, not the newly assigned value.

Comment: Update recentError with your new error msg. It will update